# I cannot access my old C: drive after system crash

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partition-recovery

I am using an Acer Aspire E1-531 running on Windows 8 Pro x64. Previously I had Windows 8 Pro x86 installed and it worked perfectly for a few months. But yesterday the system crashed and I was not able to repair it. As I had Ubuntu 13.04 installed, I made the necessary backups and installed Windows 8 Pro x64 in an unused partition. But now I cannot access my old C: drive (Which now appears as D: Drive) via explorer. It shows

`Location is not available
D:\ Is Not Accessible.
Access is denied.`

I tried using the Security tab and setting the permissions but it is not working.
**I can access the files via Ubuntu or an Elevated Command Prompt terminal.**

Comment: My guess is that the drive got corrupted. You'll probably have to reformat with GParted, or the like.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I can see all the files and use them in Ubuntu and also via CMD (Admin). I was able to copy files using `xcopy` in CMD.